# For which values of x do the vectors $(x,0,x + 1),(1,x,1),(0,x,−x)$ form a basis for R3?

Tags: linear-algebra

For which values of x do the vectors $(x,0,x + 1),(1,x,1),(0,x,−x)$ form a basis for R3?

Is 1 a correct answer to this. The vectors would each be linearly independent, however this seems too simple and I'm guessing theres an error somewhere.

If 1 works then it would seem any real number would work since the location of the 0 in the first and last vector will always mean the three vectors are linearly independent, right?

Comment: Hint: take the determinant of the three vectors. You obtain a polynomial in $x$. The vectors are linearly independent iff the determinant is nonzero.

Answer (score 4):

Guide:

- Put those vectors as rows of a matrix, compute the determinant.
- If they form a basis, the determinant would not take value zero, hence you just have to find the root of the charactheristic polynomial and avoid those root to make it a basis.
- Remark: Find all values rather than find one that works.

Edit:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & 1 \\ 0 & x & - x \\ x & 0 & x+ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Perform $R_3-xR_1$:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & 1 \\ 0 & x & - x \\ 0 & -x^2 &  1\end{bmatrix}$$

Perform $R_3+xR_2$:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & 1 \\ 0 & x & - x \\ 0 & 0 &  1-x^2\end{bmatrix}$$

To make it nonsingular, each column must have a pivot point, hence we require $x \neq 0$ and $1-x^2 \neq 0$.

Hence the conditions that you need are $x \neq 0$ and $1-x^2 \neq 0$.

Comment: This definitely looks like the easiest way to do it. However, the class hasn't gotten to determinants yet; is there a method to do this without using determinants. Organizing them in a matrix is in line with what the class is doing though

Comment: I see, what about organizing them as a matrix then reduce them to RREF? If it is a basis, the RREF is the identity matrix.

Comment: You can also apply the definition: let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a(x,0,x+1)+b(1,x,1)+c(0,x,-x)=(0,0,0)$. Then you obtain a system that you can resolve.

Comment: edited to include more details, one common mistake is division by $0$.

Answer (score 1):

How did you find this value?

You can also "glue" the vectors together to form a matrix (dimension 3x3), and try to find its determinant. You will obtain a polynom in $x$ and the zeros of this polynom are the values for which the three vectors are linearly dependant.

Answer (score 0):

A basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ must have three linear independent vectors, so the equation
$$
\lambda_1 (x,0,x+1)^t + \lambda_2 (1,x,1)^t + \lambda_3 (0,x,−x)^t = (0,0,0)^t
$$
is allowed to have only the solution $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3) = (0,0,0)$. In matrix form
$$
A \lambda = 0 \iff \\
\begin{pmatrix}
x & 1 & 0 \\
0 & x & x \\
x+1 & 1 & -x
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 \\
\lambda_2 \\
\lambda_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We can now go for the determinant of the matrix, which must not vanish for the solution to be unique, or we solve the homogeneous linear system and check what influence $x$ has on the number of solutions.

**Method A: Solving the linear system**

Still open are the possibilities one solution or infinite many solutions, as we know the null vector is a solution the case no solution is not applying here.

In augmented matrix form we have:
$$
A \lambda = 0 \iff [A|0] \iff \\
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
x & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & x & x & 0 \\
x+1 & 1 & -x & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
x & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & x & x & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -x & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
**Case 1:** For $x\ne 0$ we can divide by $x$ and have
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1/x & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -x & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1/x & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1/x & -x & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\to \\
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1/x & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/x-x & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
**Case 1.1:** For $1/x-x \ne 0$ we can divide by $1/x-x$ and get
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -1/x & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
so for 
$$
x\ne 0 \wedge 1/x-x \ne 0 \iff \\
x\ne 0 \wedge 1/x \ne x \iff \\
x\ne 0 \wedge 1 \ne x^2 \iff \\
x \not\in \{-1, 0, 1 \}
$$
the vectors are linear independent. As three linear independent vectors form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ we are done with this case.

**Case 1.2:**
For $x \ne 0$ and $x \in \{ -1, 1 \}$, which means $x=\pm 1$ we have
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & \mp 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
which gives the infinite many solutions $\lambda = (0, 0, \lambda_3)$. So in this case the three vectors are linear dependent, we have no basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**Case 2:** For $x=0$ we have
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
which again gives the infinite many solutions $\lambda = (0, 0, \lambda_3)$. So in this case we have no basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**Answer:**

For $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1, 0, 1\}$ the three vectors form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**Method B: Checking the determinant**

$$
\det A = \\
\left\vert
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & 1 & 0 \\
0 & x & x \\
x+1 & 1 & -x
\end{array}
\right\vert
=
\left\vert
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & 1 & 0 \\
0 & x & x \\
1 & 0 & -x
\end{array}
\right\vert
=
x
\left\vert
\begin{array}{cc}
x & x \\
0 & -x
\end{array}
\right\vert
-
\left\vert
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & x \\
1 & -x
\end{array}
\right\vert
= -x^3 + x
= -x(x^2 - 1)
$$
which vanishes for $x \in \{ -1, 0 , 1 \}$. For these $x$ values we have no unique solution to $A\lambda = 0$, which means the vectors are linear dependent and form no basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Any other real value will lead to a basis.